# Bootstrap: Search box disappears on touch in collapsed Navbar mode

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

I have a search box placed inside a bunch of `<li>` tags in my `Bootstrap Navbar`. It works fine in regular mode; however, when collapsed, it disappears upon touch, along with the rest of the drop-down. Here's the HTML markup:

```
<div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="bootstrap/img/gray_logo.png" class="site-logo"><span class="site-name-first">Always</span><span class="site-name-second">Spanish</span></a>
        </div>

        <!-- Navbar links -->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" ng-controller="HeaderController">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li ng-class="{ active: isActive('/about')}"><a href="#about">About</a></li>
                <li ng-class="{ active: isActive('/blog')}"><a href="#blog">Blog</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Premium</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Books</a></li>
                <li><a href="javascript:;" data-target="#contact" data-toggle="modal">Contact</a></li>
                <li>
                  <!-- Search box --> 
                  <form class="navbar-form pull-right search-box" role="search">
                    <div class="input-group">
                      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" name="srch-term" id="srch-term">
                      <div class="input-group-btn">
                        <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i></button>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </form>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

I understand this is by design as the drop down must disappear once an item is tapped. But this functionality also means one wouldn't be able to use the search box in the collapsed mode. Is there any (preferably pure CSS) workaround? Here's the drop down I am talking about:

[image]

This is what the navbar looks like on a regular desktop viewport:

[image]

Here's the complete CSS:

```css
* {
    border-radius: 0 !important;
}
@media (max-width: 760px) {
    h1 {
 font-size: 210%;
    }
    .jumbotron p {
     font-size: 120%;
    }
}

.navbar-text > a {
 color: inherit;
 text-decoration: none;
}

body {
 padding-top: 50px;
}

.row-padding {
 padding-left: 20px;
 padding-right: 20px;
 padding-bottom: 50px;
}

p {
 font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
 font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
}

.site-name-first {
 padding-left: 10px;
 font-family: 'Caesar Dressing', cursive;
 font-size: 1.5em;
 color: #6495ed;
}
.site-name-second {
 font-family: 'Caesar Dressing', cursive;
 font-size: 1.5em;
 color: #ff6666;
}

.site-logo {
 float:left;
 margin-top: -8px;
 width: 36px;
}

/* CSS to change Navbar collapse threshold [START]
===================================================================*/
@media (max-width: 991px) {
    .navbar-header {
        float: none;
    }
    .navbar-toggle {
        display: block;
    }
    .navbar-collapse {
        border-top: 1px solid transparent;
        box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.1);
    }
    .navbar-collapse.collapse {
        display: none!important;
    }
    .navbar-nav {
        float: none!important;
        margin: 7.5px -15px;
    }
    .navbar-nav>li {
        float: none;
    }
    .navbar-nav>li>a {
        padding-top: 10px;
        padding-bottom: 10px;
    }
    .navbar-text {
        float: none;
        margin: 15px 0;
    }
    /* since 3.1.0 */
    .navbar-collapse.collapse.in { 
        display: block!important;
    }
    .collapsing {
        overflow: hidden!important;
    }
}
/* CSS to change Navbar collapse threshold [END]
===================================================================*/

@media (min-width: 761px) {
    .navbar-default {
 background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9);
 border-bottom: 0px;
 color: #666666;
 margin: 0px;
    }
}
@media (max-width: 760px) {
    .navbar-default {
 background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
 border-bottom: 0px;
 color: #666666;
 margin: 0px;
    }
}

/*.search-box {
 margin-right: -15px;
}*/

.navbar-static-bottom {
 background-color: #ffcc00;
 border: none;
 color: #665100;
 margin-bottom: 0px;
 padding-top: 0px;
}
.navbar-static-bottom .socials {
 color: #665100;
}
.footer-text {
 padding-top: 17px;
}
.footer-text a {
 color: #665100;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:focus {
 outline: none;
 color: #70704c;
 font-weight: 700;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a:focus {
 background-color: #ffffff;
 box-shadow: inset 0 -5px 0 0 #665100;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:hover {
 background-color: #ffffff;
 box-shadow: inset 0 -5px 0 0 #cca300;
 color: #cca300;
 transition: color 0.15s ease;
}

/* when a dropdown menu item is clicked open */
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .open > a,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .open > a:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .open > a:focus {
 background-color: #ffffff;
 box-shadow: inset 0 -5px 0 0 #cca300;
}

.home-thumb img:hover {
 -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
    -moz-transform: scale(1.1);
     -ms-transform: scale(1.1);
      -o-transform: scale(1.1);
         transform: scale(1.1);
}
.thumbnail img {
 -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
      -o-transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
         transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
 width: 100%;
}
.thumbnail {
 overflow: hidden;
}

.bg-gray {
 background-color: #f9f9f9;
}

.facebook-color:hover { color: #3b5998; }
.twitter-color:hover { color: #4099ff; }
.googleplus-color:hover { color: #d50f25; }
.youtube-color:hover { color: #c4302b; }
.pinterest-color:hover { color: #c92228; }

.top-jumbotron {
 background: #ffcc00;
 height: 500px;
 margin: 0px;
 border: none;
}
.second-jumbotron {
 margin: 0px;
 background: #332800;
 color: #ffcc00;
 font-size: 500%;
 line-height: 50%;
 padding-top: 0.3em;
 padding-bottom: 0.6em;
 font-family: 'Mr Dafoe', cursive;
}

.contact-box {
 border-color: #ffcc00;
}
.contact-title {
 text-align: center;
 background-color: #ffcc00;
 border-color: #ffcc00;
}
.contact-title h4 {
 font-size: 220%;
 color: #545454;
}
.contact-body {
 background-color: #ffea99;
 border-color: #ffea99;
 color: #545454;
}
.contact-footer {
 background-color: #ffcc00;
 border-color: #ffcc00;
}
.contact-field {
 background-color: #fff9e5;
 box-shadow: #b2b2b2 0px 0px 8px;
}
.contact-field:hover,
.contact-field:focus {
 background-color: #fff;
 box-shadow: #b2b2b2 0px 0px 03px inset;
}
.contact-field-single {
 height: 3em;
}
.contact-send {
 background-color: #4c3d00;
 border-color: #4c3d00;
 color: #ffffff;
 width: 7em;
}
.contact-send:hover,
.contact-send:focus,
.contact-send:active {
 background-color: #2d2400;
 border-color: #2d2400;
 color: #ffffff;
}
.contact-close {
 background-color: #938a66;
 border-color: #938a66;
 color: #ffffff;
 width: 7em;
}
.contact-close:hover,
.contact-close:focus,
.contact-close:active {
 background-color: #81774c;
 border-color: #81774c;
 color: #ffffff;
}
.airmail {
 width: 50px;
 float: left;
 padding: 0px;
}

.pre-footer-jumbotron {
 background-color: #ffefb2;
 height: 50px;
 margin-bottom: 0px;
}
```

Comment: well, easiest solution is hide search box in collapse mode..or provide any live link so i will try my best to understand your issue..

Comment: could you please include your css

Comment: Don't have a live link yet because I am still building the site out on my localhost. Just updated the question with the complete CSS. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I'm concerned the easiest solution is to remove the `form` from `li` and add it separately as described in bootstrap documentation.

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li ng-class="{ active: isActive('/about')}"><a href="#about">About</a></li>
            <li ng-class="{ active: isActive('/blog')}"><a href="#blog">Blog</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Premium</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Books</a></li>
            <li><a href="javascript:;" data-target="#contact" data-toggle="modal">Contact</a></li>

        </ul>
          <form class="navbar-form pull-right search-box" role="search">
                <div class="input-group">
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" name="srch-term" id="srch-term">
                  <div class="input-group-btn">
                    <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i></button>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </form>
```

[bootstrap documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar)

Comment: If I do that, the search box moves awkwardly to the left of the rest of the <ul> elements. This is despite the `pull-right` class applied to the search form.

Comment: Also, this does nothing to resolve my original issue, i.e. that of the search box (and the rest of the drop down menu) disappearing upon touch in collapsed mode.